# Reorganize dataset in Xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I am new to using xarray in python. Actually, I work in a jupyter environment to view my satellite data.

[image: My Dataset]

Usually I Have time, latitude and longitude dimensions only which allows me to display a map. But here, i have these dimensions but accompany others et not organized as usual so it don't display a map. So, i want to know which command of xarray i have to use to just display data with only the three dimensions (time, latitude, longitude) and in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats! You've made it to xarray's deep end :)

You have data variables in there that I would consider to be [non-dimensional coordinates](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#coordinates): `[time, valid_time, latitude, longitude, lambert_azimuthal...]`. You can think of non-dimensional coordinates as additional labeling information about the coordinates in your arrays, but which you don't generally want to do math on. You can categorize these as coordinates rather than data_variables with [`ds.set_coords`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.set_coords.html), e.g.:

```py
# skipping lambert ...
ds = ds.set_coords(['time', 'valid_time', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
```

You also have dimensions without coordinates. In your dataset, `member` is a dimension of `rdis` but does not appear in the coordinates list. See the docs on [creating a DataArray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#creating-a-dataarray) for an example. You can select elements from member as if it's a RangeIndex (e.g. containing elements `[0, 1, .., 24]`

Finally, for the most difficult part - you have [multi-dimensional coordinates](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html) `latitude(y, x)` and `longitude(y, x)`. These are a bit trickier to work with. Usually this occurs when your data is in a particular cartographic projection. The docs I linked to above have a helpful starting point.

As a quick example (paraphrased from the docs), you can plot your projected data on a map with cartopy:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_global()
ds.rdis.isel(step=0, member=0).plot.pcolormesh(
    ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), x="longitude", y="latitude"
)
ax.coastlines()
```

Also relevant to multidimensional coords:

- [how-to-subset-data-using-multidimensional-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818927/how-to-subset-data-using-multidimensional-coordinates-using-python-xarray) by filtering the data to a matching block of data with xr.where
- [Selecting the nearest lat/lon with multi-dimensional coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64431809/3888719) by transforming the lat/lons to a target CRS and selecting using x/y directly
- [is it possible to convert 2d coordinates into 1D dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571866/is-it-possible-to-convert-2d-coordinates-into-1d-lat-lon-dimensions-for-an-xarra) - hint: [use xESMF](https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to regrid

Comment: Thanks for your answer this will help me a lot :)